# Finding char "\x00" in a varchar field

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to find rows that contain certain unprintable characters and encounter some inconsistent behaviour of various string functions. The field is of type `VARCHAR`. Here are the queries:

`select ascii(substring(AddressTail, 17, 1)) from Address where ID = 1934484` returns 0

`select charindex(char(0), substring(AddressTail, 17, 1)) from Address where ID = 1934484` returns 1 which is expected

but

`select charindex(char(0), AddressTail) from Address where ID = 1934484` returns 0 which is quite strange.

So, how to find the rows that contain byte zero? SQL Server version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU9) (KB4515435) - 13.0.5479.0 (X64)`

Comment: can you provide reproducible example, so that other can analyse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a binary `COLLATE` clause - below example shows examples of using it with `CHARINDEX` and `LIKE`

```
SELECT  CHARINDEX(char(0) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, txt)
FROM test
WHERE txt COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 LIKE '%' + char(0)  + '%'
```

NB: The documentation for [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) does state

> 0x0000 (char(0)) is an undefined character in Windows collations and
>   cannot be included in `CHARINDEX`.

but nonetheless it does work in practice. Perhaps a SQL binary collation (such as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN`) would be a safer choice due to that however.

Answer (score 1):

> how to find the rows that contain byte zero?

SQL server somehow badly understands \x00...

Maybe this trick will help you slightly?

```sql
create table test (id int, txt varchar(8));

insert into test values 
(1, '123' + char(0) + '456'),                -- in the middle
(2, '123' + char(0)),                        -- at the end
(3, char(0) + '456'),                        -- at the beginning
(4, '12' + char(0) + '34' + char(0) + '56'), -- in the middle
(5, '123456');                               -- absent
```

```sql
select id, pos
from test
cross apply ( select number + 1 pos 
              from master..spt_values 
              where type='P'
                and number < len(txt) ) numbers
where substring(txt,pos,1) = char(0)
order by id;
```

Output

> ```
> id | pos
> -: | --:
>  1 |   4
>  2 |   4
>  3 |   1
>  4 |   3
>  4 |   6
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a collate on the searched for ascii null, @MartinSmith suggested, you can as well SQL collate the string potentially holding it:

```
CHARINDEX(CHAR(0), s COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS ascii_null_pos
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5c7ae4/1).

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.